# Smart Contract's Integrity

Tags: blockchain, ether, tokens

If smart contract code is visible to everyone, can't I just copy the entire contract code and make my own contract and deploy it on Blockchain.
So this way many duplicates will be present and one can easily copy the business idea of others.
How to prevent this?

Comment: Maybe you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart contract codes are not directly visible to everyone. If you choose to, you can publish the source code and link it to the scanners for everyone to see.

The bytecode can also be reverse-engineered to get *some* sort of source code but it's typically not very readable. As with all reverse-engineered codes. This you can't prevent.

Furthermore, Ethereum (or its community) encourages developers to be open. The reason is trust through transparency: if the source code is known everyone can check it to make sure they know exactly what the contract does. People feel safer giving away their hard-earned Eth to contracts which they know to be honest.